# Es can validate data before insert/update?

Tags: elasticsearch

If i insert a string data to a number field,`es` will resp `[failed to parse [xxx]]; nested: NumberFormatException[For input string: "xxx"]`.

I can validate data before insert to avoid the exception?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you ingest your data to Elasticsearch but there is some different options to solve this situation.

For ES 5.x, there is ingest node API to manupilate data before inserting to ES. You can check it. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/ingest.html

For older versions, you should solve these problems some custom solutions. You should update your porcessors if you use logstash. You should change your custom script to cast your field to integer/number if you use a script which was written by you.